# Areas of display in LibreOffice not being refreshed

Tags: refresh, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer

I was experiencing some problems while editing the layout of pivot tables [ 1 ] with LO 5.1.2.2 (the default that comes with Ubuntu 16.04) and so decided to reinstall it. The problem is now gone.

However I'm experiencing a weird one now with the refreshing of some areas of the working window. For example, in Calc, whenever moving across cells the range field does not refresh at all:

[image]

In Writer, when selecting different types of text (font, size, etc) the commands on the menu experience the same annoying issue:

[image]

Would it be something with the configuration? I tried to enable/disable hardware acceleration but nothing changed. When trying to enable OpenGL, LO crashes. This is my actual config:

[image]

Any hint is appreciated!

Cheers!

Lucas

[ 1 ] - https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/70217/possible-bug-in-libreoffice-5122-with-pivot-tables/

Answer (score 1):

Try to install gnome-themes-standard package it worked for me.
Paweł